# How to make band composite image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, band, composite

I am wondering how I can make a band composite from three large bands files from Landsat? I was using option Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge but when I try to do it it crashes.

Comment: I guess this is for QGIS; if it is the case, please edit your question to mention it.

Comment: What do you mean it crashes?

Comment: Just crashes. I assume that this option is for rasters as tiles to be merged in one picture

Comment: Alternatively use `gdal_merge`, see the `-separate` parameter at https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is something you can achieve with a **Virtual Raster (Catalog)**. This will create a metadata file (.vrt) that QGIS treats like a merged multi-band raster without having to merge all the bands.

1. Raster --> Misc. --> Build Virtual Raster
2. Select the bands you want to use as "Input files"
3. Check "Separate" to put each input file into a single band (otherwise they will be merged spatially and all put into a single band)
4. Open the Virtual Raster (.vrt) in QGIS and treat it like a merged composite

Here is an example using a Landsat 8 scene of the Alps to create a band 7,5,2 false color composite. Creation of the Virtual Raster (urban-fcc.vrt) takes seconds and the file is 3KB in size.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes that is exectly what I need. How I can later save it as GeoTiff file?

Comment: You can right click on the layer and use "Save as..GeoTiff" or go to "Raster --> Conversion --> Translate". But this might crash your PC again, since the "merge" tool uses VRTs internally anyway.